# Move emails from one Outlook folder to another

Tags: vba, outlook

I am running this code to copy the contents from Outlook folder TODO to Outlook folder Test. Both folders exist.

I got

> "Run-time error '-2147221233 (8004010f)'

for `Set myItem = myInbox.Folders("TODO")`

I tried

`Dim myItem As Folder`

```
Sub MoveItems() 
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace 
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder 
    Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder 
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items 
    Dim myItem As Object 

    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
    Set myItems = myInbox.Items 
    Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("test") 
    Set myItem = myInbox.Folders("TODO") 
    While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing" 
        myItem.Move myDestFolder 
        Set myItem = myItems.FindNext 
    Wend 
End Sub
```

Comment: You have two subfolders in Inbox Named `TODO` & `test` ?

Comment: Yes, I have ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will move all the Files from `TODO` to `Test`

```
Sub MoveItems()

 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
 Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
 Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
 Dim myItem As Object

 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 Set myItems = myInbox.Items
 Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("test")

 Set myItems = myInbox.Folders("TODO").Items

 'Debug.Print myItems.Count

 For i = myItems.Count To 1 Step -1 'Iterates from the end backwards
    myItems.Item(i).Move myDestFolder

 Next

End Sub
```

You had to loop all the items in the folder, that code was for Finding a particular mail.

**Reason why we used the Loop Backwards (Courtesy: @ComputerVersteher)**
*If you loop forward and remove an item (e.g. first one), the following items takes over position from their predecessors (e.g second-one gets first-one) and`Collection.Count`is decreased by one. Forward loop would try to fetch items up to starting`Collection.Count`, but the item with last index isn't available any longer. When moving backward, you start with the last item and if you remove it, the next item (index-1) is still available as it retains position. Btw,`For Each`loops produce strange results too and should be avoided when deleting items.*

Comment: and if i want to copy from deleted items ?
 Set mydeltedfoler = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeleted Items)
 Set myItems = myFolder.Folders("Deleted Items").Items

Comment: there is a space in there what is not needed. SOlved it thanks.